# Hover Not Staying Long Enough

Tags: html, hover

The following code creates a NAV bar with hover lists.

The hover works but I have to move my mouse quickly down the hover list to make sure it stays open on hover - ie it flashes off very quickly . Do I need to squeeze the top of the hover closer to the main NAV bar ? Any help much appreciated.

```
    /* Navigation Style */ 
    .dropdown { position:relative; font-family: arial, sans-serif; width:100%; height:40px; border:1px solid #666666; font-size:14px; color:#ffffff; background:#333333; z-index:2; } 

    /* Basic List Styling (First/Base Level) */ 
    .dropdown ul {padding:0; margin:0; list-style: none;} 
    .dropdown ul li {float:left; position:relative;} 
    .dropdown ul li a { border-right:1px solid #666666; padding:12px 8px 12px 8px; display:block; text-decoration:none; color:#000; text-align:center; color:#fff;} 
    .dropdown ul li a:hover {color:#ffffff; background:#232323;} 

    /* Second Level Drop Down Menu */ 
    .dropdown ul li ul {display: none;} 
    .dropdown ul li:hover ul { font-size:13px; display:block; position:absolute; top:41px; min-width:150px; left:0;} 
    .dropdown ul li:hover ul li a {display:block; background:#000; color:#ffffff; width:170px; } 
    .dropdown ul li:hover ul li a:hover {background:#666666; color:#ffffff;} 

    /* Third Level Drop Down Menu */ 
    .dropdown ul li:hover ul li ul {display: none;} 
    .dropdown ul li:hover ul li:hover ul { display:block; position:absolute; left:145px; top:0; }
```

The actual NAV bar HTML is

```
  <div class="dropdown"> 
<ul> 
 <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li> 
 <li><a href="steam-railtours-all.php">Steam Rail Tours</a> 
  <ul> 
   <li><a href="steam-railtours-all.php">All Rail Tours</a></li> 
   <li><a href="vsoe-steam-railtours.php">British Pullman (VSOE)</a></li> 
  </ul> 
 </li> 
</ul> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3V4ww/1/)

Just add this simple rule:

```
.dropdown>ul>li>a:hover {
     margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

This way when you hover the button, it gets an invisible bottom margin that will extend the area that triggers the hover event. This works with multiple dropdowns as the demo shows.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your dropdown menu is 1px away from your static menu. Can be fixed by changing this one line of code:

```
.dropdown ul li:hover ul { font-size:13px; display:block; position:absolute; top:40px; min-width:150px; left:0;}
```

I changed 41px to 40px.

http://jsfiddle.net/eqH2Q/1/

Comment: Thanks - works a lot better although disappears sometimes - need to go to 39px but that does not make it look as good

Answer (score 0):

Try this line :

```
li:not(:hover) li {
display: none;
}
```

And get rid of all display: none and other hovers. It will make sublist's open when their partent list's li element is hovered, and you can add as many sublists as you want, without changing the CSS